# Explanation of syntax in for loop?

Tags: javascript, python, object, for-loop

I was trying to do some of the problems on projecteuler, and I got to the one with the sum of squares and squares of sums. I didn't want to brute force it, so I looked up the solution, which was:

```
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0

for i in ((x,x ** 2) for x in range(1,100+1)):
    sum1 += i[0]
    sum2 += i[-1]

print(sum1 ** 2 - sum2)
```

I do not get:

```
(x,x ** 2) for x in range(1,100+1)
```

I've seen this in another code golf solution in javascript too. Is this a specific syntax, or an unfamiliar way of something regular? Can someone please explain?

Comment: What is the relation to javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When confronted with complex syntax, add print statements.

```
for i in ((x,x ** 2) for x in range(1,100+1)):
    print i
```

Not too helpful.

Try this.

```
a = ((x,x ** 2) for x in range(1,100+1))
print a
for i in a:
     print i
```

Helpful?  Maybe.

Try this:

```
a = ((x,x ** 2) for x in range(1,100+1))
b = list(a)
print b
```

Hmmm.  The `for i in a` loop stops working, also.  This *generator object* seems to do it's thing once only.  Either in a for loop or in the `list()` (or `tuple()`) function but not both.

Try this.

```
 for x in range(1,100+1): 
      print x, x**2
```

Okay.  So, what have we learned?

`((x,x ** 2) for x in range(1,100+1))` is a generator expression.  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

It's "iterable" and can be used in a `for` statement or the `list()` function.

Also, we've learned to add print statements to explore confusing syntax.